# Django: What do you do when some tables aren't created, and no errors are output during syncdb?

Tags: django

My apps are installed. They used to work. Now that I made some edits here and there, I must have a syntax error, or something. Instead of telling me, Django just creates the Auth, Admin, etc apps and kills all my apps. Why? And, how can I debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are couple of places where djagno doesn't give you any useful info on error. Usually, i run `manage.py validate`. If that is not enough, i'll try `manage.py shell` and import my models by hand and see what happens.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes indeed. Last time this happened shell is exactly how I figured it out. This time I had just too many modules (like 130) to do that).

Answer (score 2):

Pass `--traceback` to `manage.py`.

Comment: Like this: `manage.py syncdb --traceback`? I tried that but it did the same thing.

Comment: @Ignacia I've had this happen before multiple times if I had a typo in an import or something like that. Normally I can find it manually, but not when I have like 18 edits, I'm having trouble.

Comment: Have you tried commenting all of your apps out of INSTALLED_APPS and just including one at a time to see if you can isolate the problem to a particular app?

Comment: @Brian Thanks. That's what I did, and it sure enough was just an import that was broken.